# combine effects in one NgRx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have similar effects and want to combine it in one but dont know how to do it

Here's my effects (I need to pass different `id` depends on action type):

```
setTopics$ = createEffect(
  () => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(setTopics),
    map((action) => 
      this.service.set(action.payload.id))),
  { dispatch: false });

setHeadlines$ = createEffect(
  () => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(setHeadlines),
    map((action) => 
      this.service.set(`ldb:${action.payload.id}:0`))),
  { dispatch: false });
```

I tried to combine actions in `ofType` like  `ofType(setTopics,setHeadlines)`, but how to pass different ids in `this.service.set()`

Would be really grateful for help!

Comment: Look in to how to attach payload to action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways

1. if you want to keep the effect generic to just set what it receives, the set headlines action can set `ldb:<id>:0` in payload as label and setTopics payload will set label same as id( or if you don't want label in setTopics you can check if label exists in effect then use label else id )
2. If you don't care about it being generic, you can do something like this

```
 if (action.type === actionsType.ACTION1) {
    value = action.payload.id
  } else if (action.type === actionsType.ACTION2) {
    value = `ldb:${action.payload.id}:0`
  }
 this.service.set(`ldb:${action.payload.id}:0`)
```